# Use Output of Specific Commands as Variables to Detect if Laptop or Desktop Computer Windows BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation

I have been scratching my head over this one for a while. What I am attempting to do is add auto-detection to my computer diagnostic batch script so I can make scripts specific to laptop or desktop devices that automatically execute according to device type. There are two commands I thought I could use to detect this.

```
wmic systemenclosure get chassistypes
```

and

```
powercfg /batteryreport
```

Unfortunately I cannot seem to parse the output of either of these commands into a variable that I can actually use. [This guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120731-00/?p=7003) is what I was trying to follow, but I have ran into problems with both *wmic* and *powercfg*, *wmic* outputs cannot be filtered by token as given my example in the linked guide and *powercfg* just refuses to cooperate. Here is one of the many combinations that hasn't work

`for /f %%i in ('powercfg /batteryreport') do set RESULT=%%i`

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm hoping its a me problem not a limitation to batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open `cmd` and run `for /?` you will find that there are different functions that you can use with the command, one being `delims=` which is something you will need for `powercfg` due to the result containing spaces:

For the `wmic` one of these will do:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims={}" %%i in ('wmic systemenclosure get chassistypes ^| findstr "{"') do @set "chassistype=%%i"`
echo %chassistype%
```

or by using the `/VALUE` option and setting the variable using the standard output as variable and value:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('wmic systemenclosure get chassistypes /VALUE ^| findstr "{"') do set "%%i"`
echo %chassisTypes%
```

and `powercfg`

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %i in ('powercfg /batteryreport') do set "result=%%i"
echo %result%
```

You can obviously go with all the above commands without having to `set` the commands by simply `echo`ing them.

Comment: Wow thank you all those worked, now to continue seeing how much further I can push batch. Very helpful!

Comment: No problem, to get you started, open `cmd` and run `help` it will return a list of commands, you can run `commandname /?` for each and get a huge amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you've received an answer you appear satisfied with, I have decided to post an alternative method. I'm not sure if you are aware, but there could be several of the results which could be determined to be a `Desktop` or a `Laptop`, so a robust script would perform checks against each.

This [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) version leverages [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), instead of [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic), to parse the results. It subsequently assigns the term `Desktop`, or `Laptop` to those which I have deemed appropriate for each:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Type=" & For /F EOL^=- %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command
 "(Get-CimInstance -Query 'Select * From CIM_Chassis').ChassisTypes"^
 " | Select-Object -Property @{ Label = '-'; Expression = { Switch ($_) {"^
 " { '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '15', '16' -Eq $_ } { 'Desktop' };"^
 " { '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '14', '18', '21' -Eq $_ } { 'Laptop' };"^
 " default { '' } } } }" 2^>NUL') Do Set "Type=%%G"
If Not Defined Type GoTo :EOF
Set Type & Pause
```

The last line has been included just to show you the variable name along side its expanded value, feel free to replace that with your own code, *(using `%Type%` as necessary)*. If the script does not pause, i.e. just exits, your `ChassisTypes` output was not determined to be either a `Desktop` or a `Laptop`.